# How to speed up Adobe Acrobat Reader?

Tags: windows, adobe-reader

i think Acrobat Reader is the best pdf reader because its rendering feature (high res) , but it is too slow when jumb from page to page and when display large pdf file .

so how i can speed it up ?

i am using windows version 9.3

thanks

Comment: **Due to the heated debate in comments as well as answers on this question it has NOW BEEN CLOSED. If we cannot be objective in answering a question, the question is simply degrading the standard of this site and the response from the users in this post is unacceptable by SU standards**

Comment: @Diago: This is a useful question, only the comments aren't. Why not delete all comments (including this one) and leave the question?

Comment: @harrymc Because even some of the answer are subjective. There is not a signal answer that gives a valid and technical reason as to why it is a suitable replacement. This is honestly the worst answers I have seen on a question on SuperUser yet.

Comment: It's notable that one of the people voting to close is one of the people on the wrong end of the arguments. Sour grapes have no place on SU.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Foxit Reader free viewer](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/reader/) gives the same quality of display as Acrobat Reader, but is MUCH faster.

Comment: +1 Adobe Reader has become a bloated behemoth of an application over the last 5 years or so, and despite the many utilities available (that effectively keep the app partially loaded into memory all the time), is never going to beat a slim-line application like Foxit.

Comment: -1 This does not answer the question! More features (which people nowadays love to call bloat, just because they don't use it and THINK it is slower) do not affect the performance of your application. Foxit Reader can't even compare to the top-notch quality rendering feature of Adobe Reader which is a required specification in the question...

Comment: @TomWij: Try it out and see. Foxit results are virtually identical to Adobe - they wouldn't have any business otherwise. I do consider that a better implemented duplicate of Adobe is an answer.

Comment: Tried it, the quality looks horrible compared to Adobe... And really, if you need to call your product "Foxit's NO BLOAT PDF Reader" and mention "without using Adobe® Acrobat®" then you're doing it wrong. He wants to speed it up, not replace it by something of worse quality... They might have business, but you should compare it to the revenue, quantity and quality of Adobe.

Comment: 1) not everyone can just use Foxit (or others). Not everyone has ability to install (Granted... this may also cause some problems with ability to fix) 2) Those who can, for compatibility reasons, may still not want to. Adobe is still, weirdly enough, the standard. Same reason IE6 won't die.

Comment: WernerCD & TomWij: With 10 upvotes against 1 downvote in a few hours, I think that the verdict is clear.

Comment: @harrymc: The verdict was clear from the beginning, it does not answer the question on how to speed Adobe Reader up. It's the same like: "I want to keep using my i7 PC. How can I make my i7 PC even faster?" "Buy a [insert some non-quality material here that allows you do a lot less].". People want to use Adobe Reader to read there Adobe PDFs; it's like people that want to use their PC to play games that are meant for the PC, people that buy something else of a lower quality will not have the same benefit.

Comment: Yes, there are people that like the alternative choice and might be appreciated by peers for that, but does that allow you to play your games with the best quality or read your Adobe PDFs in a way that provides you with quantity (more and better features) and quality (more and better rendering)... No.

Comment: @harrymc: This site and question are not a place for software recommendations.

Comment: @Harrymc TomWij said it... Not everyone wants to, or CAN, replace Adobe (For various reasons). The question wasn't "Can you recommend a replacement?". The question is "I like Adobe. How do I tune it?" Popularity isn't proof of a good answer.

Comment: @TomWij: If this site and every question is not a place for software recommendations, then I'd better scrap most of my answers on this forum.

Comment: No, not "every", "in general". A software recommendation out of the blue doesn't answer this question in an objective way...

Comment: @TomWij: Many times I was much thanked by a poster for a recommendation out of the blue. If the poster fully knew the subject, he wouldn't have posted in the first place. I don't consider cutting-off of plugins or always keeping Reader in memory as a lasting solution. Believe me that I have tried them all.

Comment: @TomWij, @WernerCD - The answer was not the one asked for, but it was the one he needed. You can't speed up Adobe Reader apart from removing and disabling some features. The OP already has that option from the other answers. This is a sensible alternative to Adobe which addresses the concerns of the OP. And this suggestion seems to be overwhelmingly endorsed but other SO members. Live with it.

Comment: @CJM: Actually, you can speed everything up if you want to. An XPerf analysis would show the bottleneck and then one could try get rid of it... Adobe Reader is not slow at all here so it's must be something that can be fixed. I would rather see this question answered objectively to learn from than a software recommendation which doesn't help at all.

Comment: @TomWij: Do not assume that the poster's computer hardware is as good as yours.

Comment: @harrymc: I don't assume that at all and it even should be left out of the equation, or else "buy new computer hardware" would be a valid answer which is a bit rude...

Comment: *To everybody who contributed a comment:* Thanks for your help, but I think the subject has been well-enough discussed and it's time to move on.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following app to see if it can do what you need. Other than that, I don't think there's much you can do.

### [PDF SpeedUp 2.01](http://www.acropdf.com/) (311KB, Freeware)

> [PDF SpeedUp](http://www.acropdf.com/pdfsu.exe) allows you to
>   significantly speed up the time it
>   takes to load Adobe Reader. If you
>   notice that when the Reader starts it
>   loads many plug-ins which you may or
>   may not need, this program simply
>   disables the plug-ins and loads only
>   the absolute necessary ones so the
>   program starts quickly. It offers
>   several options and you can also
>   manually enable or disable the
>   plug-ins as needed. PDF SpeedUp works
>   with Acrobat versions 5 through 9.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of "download this program that does it for you" (some people like DIY) or "use this other package" (not everyone can just install Foxit instead... not everyone wants to.)...

Look in the Adobe\Reader 9.0\Optional directory... README.TXT says:

> "Put unused plug-ins in the optional
>   directory."

So simply:

1) go to your Adobe\Reader 9.0\ folder
2) move everything from the plugins directory... into the optional directory. If you need something later, move it back.
3) ...
4) profit

While at it: [Harden Adobe Reader against attacks](https://anonymous-proxy-servers.net/en/jondo/applications/secure_pdf_documents_harden_Adobe_Acrobat_against_attacks)
- disable non-essential functions, like javascript, that cause the most security issues.

Answer (score 1):

[Sumatra PDF](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/free-pdf-reader.html), ditch Adobe Acrobat Reader, it's not worth the hassle in the long run. All the vulnerabilities, etc.

Although [FoxIt Reader](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/reader/) is good too, Sumatra PDF can't be beaten in terms of speed. In my opinion.

And no, the OPs questions does not in any way implies he/she's not open to alternatives, which is exactly what I gave.

Comment: "How do I make my ford run faster?". "Get rid of the Ford, and drive a Chevy instead" isn't really an answer. Question implies desire to keep current product, and just make if run faster.

Comment: @NoCanDo: This site and question are not a place for software recommendations.

Comment: @TomWij: WTF you mean this is not a place for software rec.? Last I checked software rec. are exactly the kind of thing SU allows.

Comment: @TomWij - Yes this is the place for s/w recommendations - if they address the problems that the OP is facing. It is not, however, a soapbox for one particular publisher's fanboys. The SO community has spoken and they disagree with you.

Comment: @NoCanDo: No... I don't see how this question requests software recommendations, nor do any questions of the same type as this one. Unrelated, questions that purely ask for software recommendations tend to be too open ended and result in long lists posts rather than an objective answer. Hence, it's disallowed unless it's asked explicitly and specifically...

Comment: @CJM: No... It's essential that the question should be answered; providing a workaround for the problem that lies in the question does not fall under that.

Comment: OMG, too much time wasted discussing with TomWij. Whatever floats your boat, buster. If you want to discuss whether software-rec are part of SU or not, go to meta. This here certainly is not the place to have a discussion, you so much seem to be loving. I for one am done with you.

Comment: @NoCanDo: I don't see any reason to take this standard to the meta at all. I didn't start this discussion and would rather like to see this question to be cleaned up as people can't stop arguing because they seem unsure about it. I'm here to help, I'm not here to bring non-sense...